# Cygwin Scp or Rsync permissions

Tags: unix, rsync, scp, cygwin

Why is it that whenever I Scp or Rsync files from my Windows machine using cygwin to my Ubuntu server. The copied files will all have no permissions. Rsync doesn't even work because it cannot copy files into the folders which don't have the +x permission.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the default mask for your login on the Ubuntu side. This determins the default permissions for new files or folders created by any process running as a certain user. You can find what this value is by loging in on a shell and running `umask`. For example a normal system will probably say 022, which means files get created with permissions of 644.

You could also try adding a -p (or --perms) to your rsync command to force rsync to set it's own permissions insetad of using the defaults.

Comment: They are standard on both machines.